# How to download an script from the New Google Apps Script IDE?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I would like to commit an script (.gs) I currently have in the new google apps script IDE to my company Gitlab but I see no "download" button and I would rather not copy-paste.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [clasp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp):

> clasp lets you to develop your Apps Script projects locally. You can
> write code on your own computer and upload it to Apps Script when
> you're done. You can also download existing Apps Script projects so
> that you can edit them when you're offline. Since the code is local,
> you can use your favorite development tools like **git** when building
> Apps Script projects.

Answer (score 0):

Those files are stored on Google Drive and can be downloaded from there - and therefore they can also be synchronized to a local directory, which may be a repository. Also [clasp](https://github.com/google/clasp) might also be useful (which I've suggested one minute sooner).

Answer (score 0):

The new Apps Script IDE does not have a built-in feature to push/pull files to popular repositories.

There *is* a Chrome extension that can push/pull files to both Github and Gitlab that works in the new code editor:

[Chrome Extension Link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-apps-script-github/lfjcgcmkmjjlieihflfhjopckgpelofo)

You need to enable your Apps Script API to use the Chrome extension.

If you right click an Apps Script file in your Google Drive, there is an option to download the file to your computer.  It is downloaded as a JSON file.